# Redux Online/Offline Sync for Get/Update Data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with React-Redux and I've been looking at libraries to manage to sync my data with the server. I've seen libraries like react-offline and react-persist that handle parts of my problem, but not all of it. I have these requirements:

- I have control of the API, so I can change it in any way necessary
- I don't want to send the entire data set to the client. Users will only have access to a subset of the data in the database
- I want the application to be able to be disconnected from the internet and still run normally (the area it functions in might are spotty, or totally disconnected)
- On login, a client will request all the data it will have access to
- At intervals, it will request a list of changes to the data it has access to so it can reconcile the client data locally (and invisibly)
- At intervals, or when changes occur (configurable), it will send a batch of all changes the client has made to the server

Please let me know if there are redux libraries that handle all these requirements. Also, feel free to comment if some of the requirements feel like an overengineering or not best practice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will get pretty complex if there are multiple clients doing changes while offline, and then all sending their changes to the server. You'd have to handle conflicts, since clients A and B could modify the same resource at different times. The server would then have to decide who has priority, and also inform the client that some of their changes didn't go through. The problem is that changes could be cascading (client A changes the same resource 3 times, but the server finds that client B actually changed it to something else first - A's changes would have to be dropped completely).

Comment: @timotgl The nice thing about this app for right now is clients will only be able to modify data they exclusively have access to. Moving forward, I think it's safe to say that in the case where there is a conflict, a "new data takes precedent" policy is more than adequate. Thanks for the feedback!